# Applying 2-up layout in scribus with printers´ (crop) marks

Tags: print-design, scribus

Please excuse my complete ignorance of the correct terms, but I have a set of 120mm blocks of content which I want to be cut out after printing. I can only print on A4 paper so I can cram two of each per A4 sheet.

The elements don't have a border of their own but I was hoping to be able to apply crop marks like can be applied to the page as a whole (on each corner.)

**Is there a method to calculate and insert said marks on to my printed document without having to use an entire sheet of paper per item?**

I would even settle for the correct terminology to use in my searches.

I'm using Scribus for the document creation and printing, I don't have access to any other package.

Comment: I don't use (in fact had never heard of) Scribus, but does it have the ability to place images or other documents into its own document?

Comment: It's hard to get into, I originally assumed that I could define 140mm square page size and then print them 2-up but it wouldn't let me (it would just print it on a single sheet of A4, with crop marks on the set page size, no options otherwise) so I painstakingly copy-pasted them onto A4-sized pages and manually added crop marks to the corners with two straight lines perpendicular rotated four times.

Comment: That was basically what i was going to suggest you do. I'm sure there is an easier way, but like I said, I'd never even heard of Scribus before today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment on the question, I eventually resigned to drawing on crop marks manually using a pair of lines on each corner.

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, you can't get Scribus to print '2-up' correctly with crop marks, save the document as PDF with crop marks and use Adobe Reader to print the PDF on your desktop/office printer. (That is assuming that each 'card' is one  document page. If you have the cards as page elements, then you have to to draw them yourself since Scribus has no manual crop mark tool/filter.)

In Scribus' `Save as PDF` dialog box you'll find the Crop Marks option in the `Pre-Press` tab. You should choose to embed all fonts (Fonts tab), if you plan on archiving the file or handing it over to others. If you have placed bitmap images, choose `Compression Method: lossless ZIP`

In the print dialog box of the PDF reader, set the zoom to 100% instead of using the default scale-to-fit setting.